# MediaElement doesn't play sound

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I download a sound and save it with `.mp3` extension like this:

```
var response = await client.GetStreamAsync(fileUrl);

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, isolatedStorage))
{
    using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        await response.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Now when I look to `IsolatedStorage` by isolated storage viewer, I see the file there, and I can play it, too.

I want to access and play it:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

musicMediaElement.SetSource(fileStream);
musicMediaElement.Play();
}
```

I don't hear anything. I don't know what wrong I do.

Comment: Are any errors or exceptions reported? Make sure you've subscribed to the `MediaOpened` and `MediaFailed` events to confirm it starts to play and you hear about any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't invoke Play() immediately after SetSource(). You should hook MediaOpened event, and invoke Play() in MedaiOpened event handler.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick for me in my Windows Store app - didn't get any errors and the sound wouldn't play either, so this was really helpful.